# Integrating stand alone applications inside codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, pydio

I am currently building a user admin area for my site that would require file management. I came across extplorer and ajaxplorer as tools i would like to experiment with. I just have some issues trying to integrate this within a controller or mesh it with the codeigniter template library. this needs to be inside a region within the template, if you are unsure what ajaxplorer or extploror is then please advise a way to integrate a similar application like zen cart etc. for reference... just a pointer in the right direction will be acceptable...  thanks

Comment: what kind of integration you want ?

Comment: like... say i want a file manager within code igniter just so i can easily make security checks from a core controller prior to loading the manager then i could pass through variables and objects to the application and make adjustments on the core off the file manager application. the file managers are php-javascript based, im just unsure how to get it too load within a view/controller without breaking the application.

Comment: so if i was to goto http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/filemanager then i would expect to load the template and within a region off the template i would like somepath/to/extplorer/index.php to load cleanly with all its dependencies. require somepath/to/extplorer/index.php within a view did not seem to work too well

Comment: You can simply use `include()` in your controller but if you want to use codeigniter classes inside or templating, you must do it manually

Comment: i simply did require('../path/to/extplorer/index.php') from the controller and i tried from a view aswell. ajaxplorer startup page loaded fine but for some reason it would not do anything (blank page) after processing the "installation". but within the startup page i tested some code to make sure CI's objects & functions would be processed and they were. I also thought off using a frame but this wouldn't allow accessing CI's objects etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit off digging around, I found that requiring from within a view the applications index.php works ok. The problem actually lies with the way that any sources within the document would point to (CIRoot)/index.php and not the actual applications path. to overcome this, I inserted `<base href="http://localhost/(path to ajaxplorer)" target="_blank" />` to the head tag off any html outputs making all sources relative to that path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with either ajaxplorer or extplorer, but I figured I'd give it a stab in the dark:

Perhaps you could write a wrapper object that wraps around the ajaxplorer/extplorer class/object/script, which would provide a non-conflicting interface to load and access those resources?

Then you could potentially access it by loading it as a CI "Library"??  Good luck!